# python 2.7 - reorder the output of lists with a new 'order' constraint

Tags: python, list, csv, tetgen

I know some basics in c++, but I am a beginner in python.

I have a piece of working code (see below) and I'd like to add a constraint for formatting its output, and I cannot figure out how to do it...

**Let me first explain what the program does:**

I have an input file `colors.csv` that contain a list of colors, one color a line: the colors are defined by their name and colorimetric coordinates X, Y and Z, it looks so:

```
Colorname, X1, Y1, Z1
Colorname2, X2, Y2, Z2
...etc.
```

Given any list of XYZ coordinates, contained in another input file `targets.csv` the program will give me a list of solutions in an output file `output.txt`

This solution is calculated by first triangulation of the points cloud with tetgen and then barycentric coordinates of the point in a tetrahedron, (but it doesn't matters to explain everything here...)

The solution has the form:

```
target, name0, density0, name1, density1, name2, density2, name3, density3
```

There are always only 4 names and associated densities.

It will look for example like this:

```
122 ,PINKwA,0.202566115168,GB,0.718785775317,PINK,0.0647284446787,TUwA,0.0139196648363

123 ,PINKwA,0.200786239192,GB,0.723766147717,PINK,0.0673550497794,TUwA,0.00809256331169

124 ,PINKwA,0.19900636349,GB,0.72874651935,PINK,0.0699816544755,TUwA,0.00226546268446

125 ,OR0A,0.00155317194109,PINK,0.0716160265958,PINKwA,0.195962072115,GB,0.730868729348

126 ,OR0A,0.00409427478508,PINK,0.0726192660009,PINKwA,0.192113520109,GB,0.731172939105

127 ,OR0A,0.00663537762906,PINK,0.073622505406,PINKwA,0.188264968103,GB,0.731477148862
```

**What I would like to do now?**

For practical reasons, I would like my output to follow a certain order. 
I would like a "priority list" to rule the order of the `name, density` output.

My actual program output the color names in an order that I don't understand, but anyway I need these color names to be in a specific order, for example `PINK` should always be the first `PINKwA` the second, etc.

Instead of:

```
127 ,OR0A,0.00663537762906,PINK,0.073622505406,PINKwA,0.188264968103,GB,0.731477148862
```

I want;

```
127 ,PINK,0.073622505406,PINKwA,0.188264968103,OR0A,0.00663537762906,GB,0.731477148862
```

Because my priority list says:

```
0, PINK
1, PINKwA
2, OR0A
3, GB
```

How could I simply add this function to the code below? Any idea?

**EDITED CODE (works...):**

```
import tetgen, geometry
from pprint import pprint
import random, csv
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

all_colors = [(name, float(X), float(Y), float(Z))
              for name, X, Y, Z in csv.reader(open('colors.csv'))]

priority_list = {name: int(i)
                 for i, name in csv.reader(open('priority.csv'))}

# background is marked SUPPORT
support_i = [i for i, color in enumerate(all_colors) if color[0] == 'SUPPORT']
if len(support_i)>0:
    support = np.array(all_colors[support_i[0]][1:])
    del all_colors[support_i[0]]
else:
    support = None

tg, hull_i = geometry.tetgen_of_hull([(X,Y,Z) for name, X, Y, Z in all_colors])
colors = [all_colors[i] for i in hull_i]

print ("thrown out: "
       + ", ".join(set(zip(*all_colors)[0]).difference(zip(*colors)[0])))

targets = [(name, float(X), float(Y), float(Z), float(BG))
           for name, X, Y, Z, BG in csv.reader(open('targets.csv'))]

for target in targets:
    name, X, Y, Z, BG = target
    target_point = support + (np.array([X,Y,Z]) - support)/(1-BG)
    tet_i, bcoords = geometry.containing_tet(tg, target_point)

    output = open('output.txt','a')

    if tet_i == None:
        output.write(str(target[0]))
        output.write('\n')


    else:
        names = [colors[i][0] for i in tg.tets[tet_i]]
        sorted_indices = sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name])
        output.write(target[0])
        counting = 0

        for i, name in sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name]):
            output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, bcoords[i]))
            counting = counting + 1

            if counting > 3:
                output.write('\n')
                counting = 0

output.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to encode your priority list directly in your Python code :

```
priority_list = {
    'PINK': 0,
    'PINKwA': 1,
    'OR0A': 2,
    'GB': 3,
}
```

This will let you quickly retrieve the order for a given color name. Then, you can use the `key` argument to `sorted` to sort your names by their priority. Critically, though, you need to retrieve not the sorted names but the indices of the sorted names, much like http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html.

```
sorted_indices = sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name])
```

The `enumerate` builtin annotates each name with its index in the original list of names, and then the `sorted` builtin sorts the resulting `(i, name)` pairs based on their rank in the priority list. Then we can write the names out to the file, followed by the corresponding element (using the index value) from the `bcoords` array.

```
for i, name in sorted_indices:
    output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, bcoords[i]))
```

So, here's what I'd make the final block in your code look like :

```
names = [colors[i][0] for i in tg.tets[tet_i]]
output.write(target[0])
for i, name in sorted(enumerate(names), key=lambda (i, name): priority_list[name]):
    output.write(',%s,%s' % (name, bcoords[i]))
output.write('\r\n')
output.close()
```

Here I changed your file output strategy to be a bit more Pythonic -- in general, adding strings together is largely not done, it's better instead to create a format string and fill in variables (you can also use `.format()` on the string to do this). Also, you can make multiple calls to `.write()` and they will simply continue to write bytes to the file, so no need to create a big long string all at once to write out. Finally, no need to call `str` on `'\r\n'` as it's already a string.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! To use a .csv file as my `priority_list` can I use: `priority_list = csv.reader(open('priority.csv'))` ?? Where should I insert this line?

Comment: It depends on the structure of your .csv file. If it's of the same form as you listed above, then I'd convert it to a dictionary using `priority_list = {name: int(i) for i, name in csv.reader(open('priority.csv'))}`.

Comment: Hi, something's wrong with me: I updated the code but I should have done a mistake. I edited the code above and added the message error at the end: `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: Ah, that's my mistake -- needed parentheses in the sorting key. I'll fix up the code.

Comment: Thank you, another bug's showing up: it works but the output looks like mess. Each line starts with `,` , the dictionary numbers are sneaking in between the values and names, and the 1st `colorname, density` is repeated at the end of each line... Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: If you could just check one more time my edit it would be great ;)

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look like you've quite integrated the code. Try removing the last 8 lines from your edited code. Then add a line with `else:` indented 4 spaces. Then add the code that I suggested, indented by 8 spaces (i.e. inside the else block).

Comment: Thank you so much! I reedited the code (had to add a function to control the `/n`